# Delete the rows which are not a complete quarter

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Stkcd is stock id, Trdmnt is the record time, Mretwd is the increasing number of this stock.
I have a stock excel table like above picture, I want to analyse the data for each quarter`(2015-1 2015-2 2015-3 is one quater)`, if the Trdmnt data is not a complete quater data, I will delete the incomplete row. For example:

```
000001  2011-04 0.131841
```

Don't have

```
000001  2011-05 xx
000001  2011-06 xx
```

So we need to delete

```
000001  2011-04 0.131841
```

And

```
000002  2014-12 0.275229
000002  2014-11 0.159574
```

Don't have

```
000002  2014-10 xx
```

So we need to delete

```
000002  2014-12 0.275229
000002  2014-11 0.159574.
```

The results is like follow:

[image]

Comment: Please show us what code you already have, then we can help you when it fails or where it needs improvement.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any idea about how to coding it! T_T

Comment: Well google is your best friend in that case. There are plenty of tutorials around, and with combining some of them I am sure you will arrive at a solution for your problem.

Comment: T_T I tried whole afternoon but I fail!

Comment: So except 2015-1 2015-2 2015-3 these all the others should be deleted right?

Comment: No, item include like "2014-1 2014-2 2014-3" and" 2013-4 2013-5 2013-6"  from same stock id _stkcd still not delete, because they are complete one quarter data! They are the valid data I want to reserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not so difficult but I can not use VBA. So I used to solve another language. I hope this code will help your problem.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import xlrd

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        book = xlrd.open_workbook('sample.xls')

        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

        vdict = dict()
        for row in range(3, sheet.nrows):
            id = sheet.cell(row, 0).value
            date = sheet.cell(row, 1).value
            year = int(date[0:4])
            month = int(date[5:])
            value = sheet.cell(row, 2).value

            if id not in vdict:
                vdict[id] = dict()

            if year not in vdict[id]:
                vdict[id][year] = dict()

            vdict[id][year][month] = value

        for id in sorted(vdict):
            for year in sorted(vdict[id]):
                months = [i for i in vdict[id][year]]
                q1 = [x for x in months if (x - 1) / 4 == 0]
                q2 = [x for x in months if (x - 1) / 4 == 1]
                q3 = [x for x in months if (x - 1) / 4 == 2]
                q4 = [x for x in months if (x - 1) / 4 == 3]

                if not len(q1) == 4:
                    for x in q1:
                        del vdict[id][year][x]

                if not len(q2) == 4:
                    for x in q2:
                        del vdict[id][year][x]

                if not len(q3) == 4:
                    for x in q3:
                        del vdict[id][year][x]

                if not len(q4) == 4:
                    for x in q4:
                        del vdict[id][year][x]

        for id in sorted(vdict):
            for year in sorted(vdict[id]):
                for month in sorted(vdict[id][year]):
                    value = vdict[id][year][month]
                    print '%s, %d-%02d, %s' %(id, year, month, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the linkage which can update the .xls file and will output a .csv file, it can solve the problem automatically!
http://naoya.tuntunkun.org/